# ValueError at /profile/ Required parameter name not set Request Method: GET

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, heroku, boto3

After properly deploying my app using Heroku I get this error while accessing my profile.

```py
ValueError at /profile/
Required parameter name not set
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://(domain).herokuapp.com/profile/
Django Version: 3.2.2
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Required parameter name not set
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/resources/base.py, line 118, in __init__
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python39.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 19 May 2021 18:40:44 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template /app/blog/templates/blog/base.html, error at line 10

Required parameter name not set
1   {% load static %}
2   <!DOCTYPE html>
3   <html>
4   
5   <head>
6       <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}"/>
7   
8       <!-- Required meta tags -->
9       <meta charset="utf-8">
10      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
11  
12      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
13      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
14          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
15  
16      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {% static 'blog/main.css' %} ">
17  
18      {% if title %}
19      <title>mytitle -{{ title }} </title>
20      {% else %}
```

I don't understand why i keep getting this error. I have also set the environment variables correctly.
This is my settings.py

```py
import os
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY= os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = (os.environ.get('DEBUG_VALUE') == 'True')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['yourlevelup.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('USER_EMAIL')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('USER_EMAIL_PASS')

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'ap-south-1'
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
AWS_S3_ADDRESSING_STYLE = "virtual"


DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

It says I have some error on my 10th line of base.html but it's the first time I get this error. Before the deployment, running locally, there was not any problem like this.
Everything else runs smoothly. I have also restarted my console but still not working.

Comment: you should probably post your url rule and view function ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I checked your site out and saw the full error message, it seemed that you did not set the os environment variable in your settings at `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')`.

If you read the error message on the site, you would’ve seen it say:

```
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py, line 572, in url
        params['Bucket'] = self.bucket.name …
name    'default.jpg'
parameters  None
```

Note the parameters None part, which means that the storage bucket name variable returns none which means you must have configured your environment settings incorrectly on heroku, and the `os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')` is returning Nothing. Check this out if you want to know how to set environment variables on heroku:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

**fix:**
Just run this command using the heroku cli:

```
heroku config:set AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=your_name
```

(Note you have to replace the `your_name` part with your Storage Bucket Name)

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for helping me out.